How can I specify architecture specific npm packages in package-lock.json?
I am developing on Windows and have a CI pipeline in a linux container on GitLab. I can build my Angular application on both systems successfully as long as I do not commit the package-lock.json file.
When I commit the package-lock.json (as is recommended) then platform specific win32 dependencies are included, and the build fails in the ci pipeline with:
npm error code 1
npm error path /builds/.../frontend/node_modules/lmdb
npm error command failed
npm error command sh -c node-gyp-build-optional-packages
npm error make: Entering directory '/builds/.../frontend/node_modules/lmdb/build'
npm error   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/lmdb/src/lmdb-js.o
npm error make: Leaving directory '/builds/.../frontend/node_modules/lmdb/build'
npm error /builds/.../frontend/node_modules/node-gyp-build-optional-packages/node-gyp-build.js:85
npm error   throw new Error(errMessage)
npm error   ^
npm error
npm error Error: No native build was found for platform=linux arch=x64 runtime=node abi=127 uv=1 libc=glibc node=22.11.0
npm error     attempted loading from: /builds/.../frontend/node_modules/lmdb and package: @lmdb/lmdb-linux-x64
npm error Error resolving package: Cannot find module '@lmdb/lmdb-linux-x64'
npm error Require stack:
npm error - /builds/.../frontend/node_modules/lmdb/package.json
npm error
npm error     at load.resolve.load.path (/builds/.../frontend/node_modules/node-gyp-build-optional-packages/node-gyp-build.js:85:9)
npm error     at load (/builds/.../frontend/node_modules/node-gyp-build-optional-packages/node-gyp-build.js:28:30)
npm error     at Object.<anonymous> (/builds/.../frontend/node_modules/node-gyp-build-optional-packages/build-test.js:19:19)
npm error     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1546:14)
npm error     at Object..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1689:10)
npm error     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1318:32)
npm error     at Function._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1128:12)
npm error     at TracingChannel.traceSync (node:diagnostics_channel:315:14)
npm error     at wrapModuleLoad (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:218:24)
npm error     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:170:5)
npm error
npm error Node.js v22.11.0
npm error
npm error The failure above indicates the primary issue with the native builds which are included for all major platforms. Will now attempt to build the package locally in case this can be resolved by re-compiling.

the package-lock.json includes:

    "node_modules/@lmdb/lmdb-win32-x64": {
      "version": "3.0.13",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@lmdb/lmdb-win32-x64/-/lmdb-win32-x64-3.0.13.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-UCrMJQY/gJnOl3XgbWRZZUvGGBuKy6i0YNSptgMzHBjs+QYDYR1Mt/RLTOPy4fzzves65O1EDmlL//OzEqoLlA==",
      "cpu": [
        "x64"
      ],
      "dev": true,
      "license": "MIT",
      "optional": true,
      "os": [
        "win32"
      ]
    },
    "node_modules/lmdb": {
      "version": "3.0.13",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/lmdb/-/lmdb-3.0.13.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-UGe+BbaSUQtAMZobTb4nHvFMrmvuAQKSeaqAX2meTEQjfsbpl5sxdHD8T72OnwD4GU9uwNhYXIVe4QGs8N9Zyw==",
      "dev": true,
      "hasInstallScript": true,
      "license": "MIT",
      "dependencies": {
        "msgpackr": "^1.10.2",
        "node-addon-api": "^6.1.0",
        "node-gyp-build-optional-packages": "5.2.2",
        "ordered-binary": "^1.4.1",
        "weak-lru-cache": "^1.2.2"
      },
      "bin": {
        "download-lmdb-prebuilds": "bin/download-prebuilds.js"
      },
      "optionalDependencies": {
        "@lmdb/lmdb-darwin-arm64": "3.0.13",
        "@lmdb/lmdb-darwin-x64": "3.0.13",
        "@lmdb/lmdb-linux-arm": "3.0.13",
        "@lmdb/lmdb-linux-arm64": "3.0.13",
        "@lmdb/lmdb-linux-x64": "3.0.13",
        "@lmdb/lmdb-win32-x64": "3.0.13"
      }
    },

The dependency is pulled in by @angular-devkit/build-angular:
+-- @angular-devkit/build-angular@18.2.6
| +-- @angular/build@18.2.6
| | +-- lmdb@3.0.13
| | | +-- UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY @lmdb/lmdb-darwin-arm64@3.0.13
| | | +-- UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY @lmdb/lmdb-darwin-x64@3.0.13
| | | +-- UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY @lmdb/lmdb-linux-arm@3.0.13
| | | +-- UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY @lmdb/lmdb-linux-arm64@3.0.13
| | | +-- UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY @lmdb/lmdb-linux-x64@3.0.13
| | | +-- @lmdb/lmdb-win32-x64@3.0.13

How can I specify multiple platforms to include in the package-lock.json? Or is it good practice to exclude the package-lock.json in the repository?
I also assume that manually editing the package-lock.json is not recommended as those changes are lost on regenerating the file. Is this correct?
I tried to specify multiple os versions in the package.json but this does not have any impact on the package-lock.json file.

you could try optional dependencies

You're focusing on the wrong error, the issue you have is that some packages are using very old nodejs concepts (node-gyp) that have been decommissioned for some time now. Maybe try to bring your project up to date ?

The dependency is pulled in by @angular-devkit/build-angular@18.2.6 -> @angular/build@18.2.6 -> lmdb@3.0.13  @MGX I do not think the dependency is out of date, it's the most current angular version. I added it to the question.

What's the purpose of this lmdb package ?

@Andrei when I add them to the optional dependencies I run into this error:  > ng build --configuration production --output-path ../app/target/classes/static/
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module @rollup/rollup-linux-x64-gnu. npm has a bug related to optional dependencies (https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4828). Please try npm i again after removing both package-lock.json and node_modules directory.

@MGX I do not explicitly use this lmdb package. It is a dependency of @angular-devkit/build-angular which is a standard devDependency added by creating an angular project with ng new

Thanks to the support in the comments and answer I found the following solution:
I added the following optionalDependencies and os to the package.json:
"os": [
  "win32",
  "linux"
],
"optionalDependencies": {
  "@lmdb/lmdb-linux-x64": "^3.0.13",
  "@lmdb/lmdb-win32-x64": "^3.0.13",
  "@rollup/rollup-win32-x64-msvc": "4.22.4",
  "@rollup/rollup-linux-x64-gnu": "4.22.4"
}

the rollup packages were needed after I added the lmdb packages due to the following issue: https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4828
and I used this comment provided here
Then I recreated the package-lock.json and it now works locally and in ci.
It is still very strange that standard angular project requires this additional configuration, but I am glad about this solution. The only other option I saw was to not commit the package-lock.json.

Yeah it is. It's sounds like you're using a default angular project? That indicates there's a bug to me. I encourage you to chime in on the GH issue and at least tell them what worked for you!
The suggestion of deleting your entire package-lock is unfortunately a little dangerous. Sometimes it's fine, sometimes it creates more headaches. Glad it worked for you though!

You generally shouldn't manually edit a package-lock, but I'm not above doing it. You should commit your package-lock.
It looks like lmdb specifies each cpu architecture as an optional dependency: https://www.npmjs.com/package/lmdb/v/3.0.13?activeTab=code
So when this gets run in CI or on a different platform, the wrong one gets installed from package-lock. Got it, okay.
What version of npm are you (and ci) running? This was a problem a while ago in npm. I might try deleting it from my package.json and package-lock.json and then reinstalling using npm >= 5.5.
Back then, the workaround was to configure your npmrc to not install optional deps. This of course meant that you wouldn't install any optional deps, you can read more about that on the github issue I linked.
You could of course just not commit the package-lock. This would solve your problem today, but might cause greater issues later down on the road. I would not recommend doing that if possible.
I know that yarn will attempt to install optional dependencies but not complain if they fail for this very reason. Not to suggest you should just use yarn instead, but it does surprise me to be reading about this problem again. I also see you're using node 22 so it seems unlikely you're using an outdated npm version.
I suppose if you're really stuck and want to avoid not committing your lockfile (I would) you could try installing each optional dep (of lmdb) so it gets an entry in your package-lock. That seems wrong though...
